# array of struct is passed by value rather than reference

Tags: c

Using [this](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/ccatsl/manual/node50.html) guide I was told that arrays are passed by reference. This holds when a struct looks like this:

```
struct Person{
 char* name;
 int id;
}
```

But is doesn't when the struct looks like:

```
struct Person{
 char name[20];
 int id;
}
```

When using the seconds struct, The `name` array is copied by value:

```
struct Person p1 = {"John", 1234};
struct Person p2 = p1;
p2.name[0] = 'L';

// p1.name[0] is still 'K'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was told that arrays are passed by reference.

That's not quite true. Arrays aren't passed at all, no function can take an array as an argument. When you have a function declared

```
void foo(int bar[]);
```

the type of argument that `foo` takes is actually `int *`, and when you call it

```
int arr[23];
/* fill arr with meaningful values */
foo(arr);
```

a pointer to the first element of `arr` is passed *by value*. All function arguments are passed by value in C, without exception.

Thus when you pass a `struct Person` to a function, that is passed by value, hence the members of the `struct` are copied. If one of the members is an array, that is copied too, since it is a part of the `struct`.

Comment: Uhm, sorry Daniel, but I don't understand your objection. The fact that you get a pointer to the array rather than getting a copy of the array in your function is exactly what call by reference means. Therefore one can say that arrays are always passed by reference as they are always passed with the pointer to the first element.

Comment: @junix: It's not pass-by-reference. If it was, modifying `bar` (the pointer) within `foo()` would also modify `arr` in the caller's frame. It's not the case, because it's not pass-by-reference.

Comment: You're not getting a pointer to the array, you get a pointer to its first element. And while the effect is pretty similar to passing the array by reference, from the language's standpoint, no array is passed by reference, but a pointer is passed by value. The type of the function argument isn't reference-to-array, it's pointer-to-element.

Comment: @netcoder Changing the contents of the array so it's visible for the caller is an indicator for pass-by-reference not changing the base of the array. Nevertheless I think we can agree that passing the pointer allows simulation of a call by reference.

Answer (score 2):

This holds for both. The only difference is that for the first struct you only store the pointer to the string and the id field. In the second struct you store the whole string and the id field in the struct. Therefore the first struct is approx. 8 bytes of size (assuming a 32 bit pointer) and the second struct is approx. 24 bytes of size.

**In both cases the whole struct is copied if you call the function and pass it by value.** You can check this by modifying the id field instead of the name field.

The reason to pass structs and arrays to functions by reference (as pointer) is to avoid this copy onto stack.

Edit: 
To clearify: By accessing p2.name[0] for the first struct you access a location outside of the (copied) struct somewhere else in the memory (which is not copied). If you access p2.name[0] for the second struct you access a location inside of the memory area allocated for the (copied) struct.

Reviewing your code I just found another critical part worth noting here:
As you are initializing the frist struct with String literals (hard coded strings) writing to p2.name[0] results in undefined behavior (depending on toolchain and operating system your program even could crash because of this!)

Comment: you and @tletnes have two completely different answers

Comment: @Tom No. Actually the answers are the same. Mine is a bit longer than tletnes'. Are you aware of the difference of declaring pointers and arrays?

Comment: @Tom I now updated the explaination above a bit and hope this would clearify it...

Answer (score 1):

In the first case your struct holds a pointer to a buffer of chars, in the second the struct actually contains (read: has space to hold) 20 chars.

So in the first case when you pass by value you are copying the pointer, not the value.